# $f$ is convex or concave?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

If $ f(x)$ be a concave function, what can be said about the convexity of $f(x)=1/g(x)$

I thinking don't have convexity for $1/g(x)$ because maybe $g(x)=0$  , $g(x)\leq 0$

But I have no idea for proof, my guess is true? how can Begin the proof?

Comment: So a related question.  If you know $f''(x) < 0$ for all $x$, what is the sign of $(1/f(x))''$ ??

Comment: Please consider reading, say, the first three chapters of [Boyd & Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/). This very question is addressed there.

Comment: That said: when you are trying to _disprove_ convexity, you only need one counterexample. So you need just one concave function whose reciprocal is not convex. That's not hard, don't you think?

Comment: @Michael Grant thanks, your recommended is very good :-)

Comment: @Michael Grant , please give me an example, thanks, I  try to make a counter example but, I can't:-((

Comment: What is the simplest concave function you know.

Comment: @Michael Grant i thinked about this example, is this true?$\sqrt x$ is cancave  and $\frac{1}{\sqrt x}$ is cnvex , ;-)right?